# Ruby Exerb: missing File class

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction

I this working Ruby code that i want to make an executable from with exerb on a windowspc.
When i compile hello_world.rb there is no problem running the executable but with this code 
Exerb creates my executable but when i run it i get following error

```
undefined method `write' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Here the code

```
def replace text
  replacements = [
     {:pattern => /(^ARFD0001\|.*)(FAC_12125)/, :replace_with => '\1FAC_12102'},
     {:pattern => /^ARFD0001\|121\|25\|ZIEFAC\|/, :replace_with => 'ARFD0001|121|02|ZIEFAC|'},
     {:pattern => /(^ARFD0010\|.*)(12125203)(\d{3})/, :replace_with => '\112102181\3'},
     {:pattern => /(^ARFD0010\|.*)(2030341401)/, :replace_with => '\1181701500'},
     {:pattern => /(^ARFD0019\|.*)(12125203)(\d{3})/, :replace_with => '\112102181\3'},
     {:pattern => /(^ARFD0019\|\d*\|\d*\|\d*)(\|{2})/, :replace_with => '\1|PRINT|'},
     {:pattern => /^ARFD0009\|121\|25\|/, :replace_with => 'ARFD0009|121|02|'}
  ].each{|replacement|text.gsub!(replacement[:pattern], replacement[:replace_with])}
  text
end

Dir.glob("*.txt").each{|file|File.write(file, replace(File.read(file)))}
#line above gives the error in Exerb
```

How to get this going ? There is nothing wrong with the code, in the Ruby interpreter this works but it seems i have to tell Execrb to include the File class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no write method on the `File` class. You have to first open the file and can then write to it. It can be done similar to this:

```
Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |file|
  File.open(file, 'w') {|f| f.write replace(File.read(file))}
end
```

Comment: if i check the File class indeed i see no write method. But then how it comes the code works in a normal Ruby script ? Tried it at home also, no problem, file is written. I'l try tomorrow at work to compile your code and see what difference it makes.

Comment: You are probably dealing with different ruby versions, ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have it but ruby 1.9.3 does